# Reading in CSV Files with newline characters imbedded

Tags: python, file, csv

I am currently reading in data from a csv file and inputting tokens and their definitions into a dictionary. The code works fine until it hits a place where the data in the CSV file looks like this:

```
"Token000\nip address\ntesttestest"
```

Here is my code so far:

```
for line in f:
        if "Token" in line and re.search("Token\d", line):
            commaIndex = line.index(",", line.index("Token"))
            csvDict[line[line.index("Token"): commaIndex]] = line[commaIndex + 1: line.index(",", commaIndex + 1)]
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv should help. but it's hard to test if you don't provide a little more context of your csv input.

Comment: I think the reason for the problem is that you are reading the file line by line, and yet some values in your file also contain newline character (`\n`), as it is the case for the example you provided.

Comment: If the fields have new lines and no quotes around fields, how do you know when a row ends? what separator does it use for rows? It would be helpful to show a few lines of sample csv.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
import csv

data={}
with open('your_file.csv') as csv_file:
    reader=csv.reader(csv_file, skipinitialspace=True, quotechar="'")
    for row in reader:
        data[row[0]]=row[1:]

print(data)
```

I recommend that you take a look at [csv module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Comment: I was thinking of using this but it reads the data the opposite way I have it set up. (reads vertically instead of horizontally or vice versa I can't remember). Is there a way to flip how it reads?

Comment: Well I don't know if there is anything like that (AFAIK it's not).
But I think that in standard csv, each line represents a record and I don't really understand why you would want to setup your file in another way